# how to call from GWT to Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-endpoints

We are developing a GWT web that also will be deployed as a phonegap app. Because of that we would like to use the google cloud endpoint from the GWT code to communicate to the server.

Is there any possibility of generating a gwt java client? Do we have to use the javascript one?

Which is the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786656/gwt-and-google-cloud-endpoints

Comment: Thanks for the resposne, but I don't see any answer in that post. I think the best approach is using the javascript library, but I don't know if I could generate a wrapper automatically for gwt.

Comment: See the comments. There is a library: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/

Comment: I don't see how to make a static client with that library. Is that library only for composing the calls? What I really want is to create a typed client, I have found this: code.google.com/p/google-apis-client-generator  . Do you know the best way to create a typed client for our API? maybe on top of the discovery doc or the javascript library?

Comment: You can find a good example by Brandon Donnelson including the server and the gwt part here https://github.com/branflake2267/CloudEndPoints

Comment: Hi, is there any news on this issue?

Comment: At the end I used normal gwt communiation inside the mobile and not the google api, but that was a long time ago, maybe now it is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post on how you can do RPC calls with phoneGap
http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html

If you're using RequestFactory, here's also the solution from the same author
http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-requestfactory-and-phonegap.html

Best Regards,
Zied